# How to inoffensively ask a girl if she uses drugs?

Tags: politeness, alternatives

A friend of a friend asked me recently, how to inoffensively ask a girl if she uses party-drugs or if she wants to use them right now?

He did not want to ask her if she `"blows noses"` if you know what I mean. Substances not meant by that question include h, meth or crack and any kind of injection is out of the league.

Comment: Voted to close because what is charming or polite in that context will be simply a matter of opinion.  Questions that can elicit only subjective opinions are regarded as off-topic on this site.

Comment: What is not impolite is not less a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I have rephrased the question although I think that many answers on ell are "opinion based".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Shall I remove the word "inoffensively" to make it an accepted question?

Comment: I disagree on closing as "subjective". What is offensive or inoffensive is often a matter of language, and thus appropriate here, and is often a matter of well-established use of words. Few would dispute that, for example, "You may want to reconsider that decision" is more polite than "That's a stupid idea".

Comment: If there's a polite way to ask a stranger if she would like to do some party drugs, Jay, go ahead and answer. You might also let us know how to politely ask if she's a virgin.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between inviting someone to share party drugs with you and asking about their personal practices.  Asking such a personal question raises a question in the persons mind of why are you asking?  Did I telegraph that?  Do I come across to others as someone who will do anything?  Similar to Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment about expressing your own desire to have sex with someone vs. asking them if they put out.  This is a little like asking if there is more polite wording for the compliment "You don't sweat much for a fat lady."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much of this can depend on context. If it's obvious people are taking drugs at a party, one can simply ask

> Want a hit?

or if in pill form, often the pill is offered, so it is more gesturing than speaking.

If you're making casual conversation, you might ask

> Do you like to party?

which can then lead in various directions of conversation.

Comment: "Do you party" = "Would you like some cocaine?"  I don't know who decided this, but there you go!

Comment: To give a serious answer, we're here to give answers not moral advice.  Among people who do party drugs (speed, coke, mdma etc.), "Do you party?" often means "do you take party drugs?".  But in general if you're in a situation where that kind of thing wouldn't be weird to ask, then just ask directly. Not many people are going to be pissed of if you just say "do you like MDMA" or whatever. As long as you're not weird about it; if someone doesn't like to then they can simply say "no".

Comment: If you're offering then just offer...  "Hey do you want to do line?".  "sure." or "no."  It's fine.  If you think that someone would be offended by the offer, then don't offer hahaha